# JQGRID Data Load Complete Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid  4.5.4. I need to show a popup message after the jqgrid loads completely. The GetData() method calls to render jqgrid which calls ajax to load data from database. At a time approx 1000 data gets loaded. I am using loadonce: false. ShowTransactionMessage shows popup with confirmation message.

Code Block:
GetData();
ShowTransactionMessage("dialog-message_Conf", "SpanMessage_conf", "Record Added in Cart Successfully.", "success", "SpanIcon_conf", 200, 320, true);

But the issue is before loading jqgrid data completely the popup message opens. i.e the ShowTransactionMessage block executed before jqgrid data loads completely.

Code block:

```
function (data) {
 ShowBusyLoading();
            if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                GetData();
                ShowTransactionMessage("dialog-message_Conf", "SpanMessage_conf", "Record Added in Cart Successfully.", "success", "SpanIcon_conf", 200, 320, true);
            }
        });
    HideBusyLoading();
}
```

Please suggest how to restrict opening of message popup before loading jqgrid data completely.

Comment: You should include the call of `ShowTransactionMessage` inside of `loadComplete` callback. Moreover the usage of `loadoce:false` with 1000 rows have no sense. The loading will be much more slowly from the users point of view. You should use *local or remote paging*. In case of 1000 rows would be the usage `loadonce: true` and some small `rowNum` (`rowNum: 20` for example) the best choice. Moreover I recommend to upgrade from very old jqGrid 4.5.4 to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.12.1.

Comment: The GetData() method which is used also while pageload. The same method is called for another scenario which need to call the GetData() method with ShowTransactionMessage popup messgae.
If I add ShowTransactionMessage inside loadcomplete then it will open popup while 1st time rendering of jqgrid i.e pageload time. How should I distinguish that grid is loading in page load or call through some other method i.e mentioned above scenario.

Comment: You can just sets some custom jqGrid parameter after the first loading or just use JavaScript variable, which you change after the first loading. It's very easy.

Comment: I have set a hidden variable to check whether the call is from a method or for first time page load. Its working now.

Comment: What is "hidden variable"? Just a variable?

Comment: oops typo. Its Hidden Field.

Comment: Hidden field of the grid? You mean that you have hidden column and every row of the column contains hidden cell? I suggested that you just declare `var first = true;` somewhere on the outer level of your JavaScript code, you test the value of the variable inside of `loadComplete` and you changes the variable to `false` after the first usage. In the way.